# Problem with transforming json into object model because of enum- groovy

Tags: json, groovy, spock

I have a defaultJson.json:

```
{
  "crewType": "Cockpit",
  "status": "CREATED",
  "usePoints": true,
  "points": [
    {
      "rank": "CPT",
      "defaultPoints": 0,
      "carryForwardPointsAllowed": false,
      "carryForwardPointsMax": null,
      "negativePointsAllowed": false,
      "negativePointsLimit": null,
      "accrualExpirationValue": null,
      "accrualExpirationUnit": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I created a model for this json to be able to create object from it:

```
package com.xxxx.models

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor
import lombok.Builder
import lombok.Data
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
class SomeConfig {
    private Long version
    private CrewType crewType
    private ConfigStatus status
    private String modifiedBy
    private String modifiedTimestamp
    private List<String> leaveTypes
    private boolean usePoints
    private List<PointsConfig> points
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
class PointsConfig {
    private String rank
    private int defaultPoints
    private boolean carryForwardPointsAllowed
    private Integer carryForwardPointsMax
    private boolean negativePointsAllowed
    private Integer negativePointsLimit
    private Integer accuralValue
    private AccrualUnit accuralUnit
}

enum ConfigStatus {
    DRAFT,
    CREATED
}

enum AccrualUnit {
    DAY,
    MONTH
}

enum CrewType {
    CABIN("Cabin"),
    COCKPIT("Cockpit"),
    final String value

    CrewType(String value) {
        this.value = value
    }
}
```

So I want to create the object of 'SomeConfig' model and be able to modify objects inside this object. The problem is that it doesn't work.

When I try to create this object in this way:

```
SomeConfig someConfig = new SomeConfig(DataSource.getTestData(defaultJson.json)
```

I receive this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant 
com.xxxx.models.CrewType.Cockpit

    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at com.xxxx....
```

It would work if I broke the naming convention and would made enum like this:

```
enum CrewType {
    Cabin,
    Cockpit
}
```

But we use enums with capitalized letters and this is good naming convention.

How can I approach this problem to be able to receive crewType as String from this defaultJson and somehow transform it to CrewType.COCKPIT if this string is "Cockpit" and to CrewType.CABIN if this string is "Cabin"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the object is constructed using its (Lomok generated) setters. So if you add another setter taking a string and mapping it to the enum, that could work.

```
public void setCrewType(final String crewTypeValue) {
    CrewType crewType = CrewType.values().find { it.value == crewTypeValue }
    If (!crewType) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid crew type ${crewTypeValue}")
    this.crewType = crewType
}
```